# Compilation error on stored procedure using PL/SQL in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
create or replace procedure updateStudentResult(id int,
m1 in int,
m2 in int,
m3 in int,
tot out int,
avg out float,
grd out char)
as

begin

select marks1,marks2,marks3 into m1,m2,m3 from students where sid=id;

tot:=m1+m2+m3;
avg:=(m1+m2+m3)/3;

if avg >= 85 then
grd:='A';

elsif (avg >= 65) then
grd:='B';

elsif (avg >= 50) then
grd:='C';

else
grd:='D';

end if;
UPDATE students SET 
total=tot,
average=avg,
grade=grd 
where sid=id;

end;
/
```

> PLS-00103: encountered the symbol '=' when expecting one of the following: (
>
> these are the line where the error occurs
>
> if avg >= 85 then grd:='A';
>
> elsif (avg >= 65) then grd:='B';
>
> elsif (avg >= 50) then grd:='C';

Answer (score 4):

@kevinsky is correct, you cannot use `avg` as a variable name in PL/SQL, however that is not the only issue. You also cannot assign values to IN variables like `m1`, `m2`, and `m3`. My best guess is that you meant those to be local variables seeing as the first thing you do with then is SELECT INTO them.

test table:

> ```
> create table students(
>   sid integer
> , marks1 integer
> , marks2 integer
> , marks3 integer
> , total integer
> , average number
> , grade char(1)
> );
> ```

your procedure errors:

> ```
> select * from user_errors;
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME                | TYPE      | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT                                                                                       | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER
> :------------------ | :-------- | -------: | ---: | -------: | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :-------- | -------------:
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        1 |   17 |        8 | PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:<br><br>   (<br> | ERROR     |            103
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        2 |   20 |       12 | PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:<br><br>   (<br> | ERROR     |            103
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        3 |   23 |       12 | PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:<br><br>   (<br> | ERROR     |            103
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        4 |   32 |       12 | PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:<br><br>   (<br> | ERROR     |            103
> ```

your procedure errors after fixing use of `avg` keyword:

> ```
> select * from user_errors;
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME                | TYPE      | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT                                                                                    | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER
> :------------------ | :-------- | -------: | ---: | -------: | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :-------- | -------------:
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        1 |   12 |       34 | PLS-00403: expression 'M1' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement | ERROR     |            403
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        2 |   12 |       37 | PLS-00403: expression 'M2' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement | ERROR     |            403
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        3 |   12 |       40 | PLS-00403: expression 'M3' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement | ERROR     |            403
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        4 |   12 |       43 | PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier                                                 | ERROR     |              0
> UPDATESTUDENTRESULT | PROCEDURE |        5 |   12 |        1 | PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored                                                           | ERROR     |              0
> ```

fixed procedure:

> ```
> create or replace procedure updateStudentResult(id int,
> tot out int,
> v_avg out float,
> grd out char)
> as
>   m1 int;
>   m2 int;
>   m3 int;
> begin
>
> select marks1,marks2,marks3 into m1,m2,m3 from students where sid=id;
>
> tot:=m1+m2+m3;
> v_avg:=(m1+m2+m3)/3;
>
> if v_avg >= 85 then
> grd:='A';
>
> elsif (v_avg >= 65) then
> grd:='B';
>
> elsif (v_avg >= 50) then
> grd:='C';
>
> else
> grd:='D';
>
> end if;
> UPDATE students SET 
> total=tot,
> average=v_avg,
> grade=grd 
> where sid=id;
>
> end;
> /
> ```

with no errors!:

> ```
> select count(*) from user_errors;
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        0 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=147d66f040310ba44349f87dc4263479)*

---

If the grading rules are set in stone, you may wish to use virtual columns instead of updating them at all:

> ```
> create table students(
>   sid integer
> , marks1 integer
> , marks2 integer
> , marks3 integer
> , total integer as (marks1+marks2+marks3)
> , average number as ((marks1+marks2+marks3)/3)
> , grade char(1) as (case when (marks1+marks2+marks3)/3>=85 then 'A'
>                          when (marks1+marks2+marks3)/3>=65 then 'B' 
>                          when (marks1+marks2+marks3)/3>=50 then 'C' 
>                          else 'D' end)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> insert into students (sid,marks1,marks2,marks3) values (1,55,66,77);
> ```
>
> ```
> select * from students;
> ```
>
> ```
> SID | MARKS1 | MARKS2 | MARKS3 | TOTAL | AVERAGE | GRADE
> --: | -----: | -----: | -----: | ----: | ------: | :----
>   1 |     55 |     66 |     77 |   198 |      66 | B
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab35e2a7db3f7d7b7ad8be6be1cc2c6d)*

Answer (score 1):

AVG is an Oracle keyword.  Change it to v_avg or anything and this will work.

Answer (score -2):

that's very simple, you have to insert a colon ( : ) before the equal sign ( = ) to construct a valid assignment operator ( := ).

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your contribution/participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the answers posted. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I write a good answer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (Help Centre)_ In the section **Answer the question** there is a short sentence which reads: _Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._ You might want to consider [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/218942/edit) your answer and adding an example of how it should look/work.